# RSpec spies work differently on two different classes

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, rspec, rspec-mocks

I have a class `Uploader` which takes a file and uploads it to S3. I'm trying to test that `@s3` is actually receiving a file body when `upload_file` is called. When I test that `File` is getting messages sent, the test passes. However, trying to spy on `Aws::S3::Client` does not work.

```
class Uploader
  def initialize(tmp_dir_name, bucket)
    @base_tmp_dir = tmp_dir_name
    @s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')
    @bucket = bucket
    @uploaded_assets = []
  end

  def upload_file(key, file_path)
    file = File.new(file_path)
    @s3.put_object(bucket: @bucket, key: key.to_s, body: file.read)
  end
end

RSpec.describe Uploader do
  let(:bucket) { 'test_bucket' }
  let(:base_temp_dir) { 'test_temp_dir' }
  let(:uploader) { Uploader.new(base_temp_dir, bucket) }

  describe "#upload_file" do
    let(:file) { double('file') }
    before { allow(File).to receive(:new) { file } }
    before { allow(file).to receive(:read).and_return('text') }
    before { allow(Aws::S3::Client).to receive(:put_object) }

    it "uses one file" do
      uploader.upload_file('test_key', 'file_path')
      expect(File).to have_received(:new).with('file_path')
    end

    it "sends data to s3" do
      uploader.upload_file('test_key', 'file_path')
      expect(Aws::S3::Client).to have_received(:put_object)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your code is not invoking `put_object` on `Aws::S3::Client` but on an instance thereof. Tell your spies to stop interrogating the poor class and let them unravel the uploader instance's `@s3` instance variable instead ;)

Comment: You'd probably want to mock the whole `Aws::S3::Client` service – unless you want to establish a connection to their servers for each run of each test.

Comment: @Raffael Thanks! I was thinking that might be the issue, but then was wondering if it would count that it was acting on an instance of the class... oof, my brain is in knots. FWIW, I'm using AWS's built-in mocking.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up mocking out s3 for this particular test.

```
    it "sends data to s3" do
      test_key = 'test_key'
      bucket = 'test_bucket'
      fake_s3 = instance_double(Aws::S3::Client)
      allow(Aws::S3::Client).to receive(:new).and_return(fake_s3)
      allow(fake_s3).to receive(:put_object)

      uploader.upload_file(test_key, 'file_path', record=true)
      expect(fake_s3).to have_received(:put_object).with(
        {bucket: bucket, key: test_key, body: 'text'})
    end
```

Comment: This was a lot helpful. Thanks!